# Composer SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, git, composer, bower

Trabalho em um órgão público e aqui os acessos são bem restritos. 
Venho enfrentando problemas ao tentar executar "composer install" ou "composer update", isso vale também pro NPM ou Bower.

Seguem detalhes do erro ao tentar executar "composer update":

```
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: 
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Ocorria o mesmo ao tentar "clone" e "push" no git, mas deu pra burlar usando

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://repositório
```

Já baixei o certificado ca-cert.pem e configurei o php.ini para pegar o caminho correto do certificado, mas nada funcionou.

Retorno do **composer diagnose:**

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: 
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: 
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version:
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded:
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
diagnose
```

Alguém já teve problema parecido?

Comment: Está atrás de um proxy autenticado?

Comment: Sim. Temos um proxy e um firewall que bloqueia, por exemplo, emails pessoais.

Comment: Esse proxy requer que você digite um user e senha? Rode composer diagnose e edite sua pergunta com o retorno dele

Comment: Não preciso de usuário e senha. Na verdade acho que ele autentica na hora em que faço logon no Windows.

Comment: Tive um problema parecido, mas era por causa da autenticação obrigatória do proxy.

Comment: Como resolveu? Eu faço um teste também.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26224/discussion-between-gmsantos-and-buback).

Comment: Provavelmente o firewall que controla o acesso a Internet faz aquela troca de certficado para poder analisar o conteúdo de conexões HTTPS. É um "ataque man-in-the-middle" oficializado, e o certficado que o firewall manda não é assinado por uma CA.

Comment: Amigo, tô tendo o mesmo problema, vc conseguir resolver? como?

Comment: @LeandroMacedo, o problema era com certificado SSL. O nosso firewall valida todo certificado antes de completar a requisição. Foi necessário criar regras no firewall para liberar o packagist, git, entre outros.